# C++ Clear string

Tags: c++, string, fflush

Hey guys i created a game, in the code it have `while(true)` and each time it gets as input a new string, The problem is that if i wrote first time `abc` and then in second loop `abcd`, and then `abc` it saves the last d,
I tried `str.clear()`, i tried to put `\0` in it, i tried to to `str = "";` ,i tried everything and its still the same.

Here is some of the code:

```
    std::string whoplayed;
int res = getPlayersNames();
if(res == -1)
    return;
std::cout << "ok " << splayername << " please start: (Starting from south) S->N->S->N...." << std::endl;
std::string temp = "";
std::string playername = "";
while(true)
{
std::getline(std::cin,temp);
for(int i=0;i<(signed)temp.size();i++)
    {
        if(temp[i] != ':')
        {
            playername[i] = temp[i];
        }
        else break;
    }

    char c;
    for(int i=0;i<(signed)temp.size() ; i++)
    {
        if(temp[i] == ':' && temp[i+1] == ' ')
        {
            c = temp[i+2];
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

This is part of the code.. i cant post it all.. when i print playername in third loop with inputs abc, abcd ,abc( sure with correct format that i need not like this) it saves the last d

Comment: Write temp definition.

Comment: Please include a short, self contained, compilable example. The code you provide does not show us what the problem is.

Comment: Updated, this is a part of the code that contains the problem

Comment: A std::string is an intelligent, managed object. You're not supposed to stick your fingers into its guts like that. If you're trying to parse a string with some kind of colon separator, try find, substr, etc.

Comment: i know but the parsing is not the problem, my code working fine as i desired, the only problem is that in the loop x its saves the string that was in loop x-1 like if it was abcd in loop x-1 and in loop x i write abc it will be in loop x abcd not abc..

Comment: `playername` is empty. Indexing into it (`playername[i]`) doesn't extend it, but is undefined.

Comment: @molbdnilo but this is not the problem here^^ you think that this is it?

Comment: Try to remove from while (true) all, but      `std::getline(std::cin,temp);  
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;  
    std::cout << temp.size() << std::endl;`  
and post the result.

Comment: @Saif Yes. "Undefined" means that anything can happen - your program is not a valid C++ program. If you want to add characters to a string, use `+` or `+=`.

Comment: molbdnilo Solved!, apparently the problem was in the for that you mentioned and @Adrian May mentioned, i just re-typed it like this and used substr
and put playername.clear() in the first row in while and solved :), 
thanks to all
molbdnilo or Adrian May Write a comment with your answer and i will accept it thanks very much, btw the game is Awari that i am doing and its done

Comment: Happy coding Saif. You can vote up comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

To clear a std::string use

```
std::string sStr;
sStr.clear();
```

To copy all characters from string temp to string playername you could use string::find_first_of(...) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/ in combination with std::copy http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/

Comment: thing of putting your temp-variable into the while-loop

Comment: tried in many places, in first after the loop starts and in the end after i use the the playername

@Post-2: you mean to init temp in while, i think i tried this

Comment: as already mentioned in the other comments try to not copy the characters manual, instead use the specific std::functions

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
string test;
test = "hello";

cout << test << endl;

test = "";
test = "abc";

cout << test << endl;
```